# Cannot `.setActivity()` using external functions module

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, discord.js, eval

I was trying to setup the bot's `.setActivity()`, but it doesn't seem to work, though, if I do it using the `eval` command, it actually sets it and works. Is this because I tried calling an external functions module?

---

**Files**

- Essentials: [`./resources/utils/essentials.js`](https://github.com/KyIDevs/KyIDevs-Essentials/blob/master/resources/utils/essentials.js)

```js
placeHolder(client, string) {
   const owner = client.users.cache.get(client.config.admin.owner.id);
   if (typeof string === "string") {
     return string
       .replace(/%totalCommands%/g, client.commands.array().length)
       .replace(/%clientName%/g, client.name)
       .replace(/%clientId%/g, client.user.id)
       .replace(/%clientDescription/g, client.package.description)
       .replace(/%clientUsername%/g, client.user.username)
       .replace(/%clientTag%/g, client.user.tag)
       .replace(/%clientDevName%/g, client.dev.name)
       .replace(/%clientDevHelpers%/g, client.dev.helpers.join(", "))
       .replace(/%clientDefaultPrefix%/g, client.def.prefix)
       .replace(/%clientGuildCount%/g, client.guilds.cache.size)
       .replace(/%clientChannelCount%/g, client.channels.cache.size)
       .replace(/%clientPackageName%/g, client.package.name)
       .replace(/%clientVersion%/g, client.package.version)
       .replace(/%clientLicense%/g, client.package.license)
       .replace(/%clientAvatarURL%/g, client.avatar)
       .replace(/%clientRepository%/g, client.package.repository)
       .replace(/%clientAuthor%/g, client.package.author)
       .replace(/%clientOwnerUsername%/g, owner.username)
       .replace(/%clientOwnerTag%/g, owner.tag)
       .replace(/%clientOwnerID%/g, owner.id)
       .replace(/%clientMainFile%/g, client.package.main)
       .replace(/%clientOwnerAvatarURL%/g, owner.avatarURL() || owner.defaultAvatarURL)
       .replace(/%clientOriginalAuthor%/g, client.package.original_author);
   } else {
     return string;
   }
 }
```

- Event Handler for `ready`: [`./resources/events/ready.js`](https://github.com/KyIDevs/KyIDevs-Essentials/blob/master/resources/events/ready.js)

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Essentials = require("../utils/essentials.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "ready", // Event Name
  async execute(
    client, event
  ) {
    let activity = {};
    async function setActv() {
      activity.type = client.config.client.presence.activity.default.name;
      activity.status = client.config.client.presence.activity.status;
      activity.name = await Essentials.placeHolder(client, client.config.client.presence.activity.default.name);
      client.user.setActivity(activity.name, {
        type: activity.type
      });
      client.user.setStatus(activity.status);
    }
    client.footer = Essentials.placeHolder(client, client.config.client.settings.footer);
    try {
      // Set Activity every 30 seconds
      setInterval(async () => {
        await setActv().catch(err => Essentials.log(client, error))
      }, 5000);
    } catch (error) {
      Essentials.log(client, error);
    }
  
    // Bot Ready Log //
    console.log(
      `Logged in as ${client.user.tag}.\n`
      + `There are ${client.users.cache.size} users and/or bots online.\n`
      + `${client.user.tag} connected to:\n${client.guilds.cache
        .map(g => g.name)
        .join(", ")}`
    );
  }
};
```

- Main bot file: [`./bot.js`](https://github.com/KyIDevs/KyIDevs-Essentials/blob/master/bot.js)

```js
client.events = new Discord.Collection();
var eventFiles = fs
  .readdirSync(`./resources/events`)
  .filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));
for (var file of eventFiles) {
  var event = require(`./resources/events/${file}`);
  client.events.set(event.name, event);
  console.log(`Loading event handler for event "${event.name}".`);
}

client.on("ready", async () => {
  const event = client.events.get("ready");
  if (event) {
    try {
      await event.execute(
        client, event
      )
    } catch (err) {
      Essentials.log(client, err)
    }
  } 
});
```

- Eval command: [`./resources/commands/eval.js`](https://github.com/KyIDevs/KyIDevs-Essentials/blob/master/resources/commands/eval.js)

````js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Essentials = require('../utils/essentials.js')

module.exports = {
  id: "eval",
  name: "Eval", // Command name
  description: "A simple eval tool to use on Discord.", // Command Description
  aliases: ["evl", "ev"], // Command Aliases
  category: "Utilities",
  cooldown: 5000, // Command cooldown
  examples: ["eval message.author.id", "eval process.cwd()"], // Command Examples
  usage: ["<args>"], // Command Usage
  permissions: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY"], // Command Permissions
  memberPermissions: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY", "MANAGE_SERVER"], // User is required to have these permissions
  admin: true, // Command is admin only
  async execute(client, command, message, args, auth, channel, guild) { // Function async execute()
    // Command Starts Here
    try {
      let evaled = eval(args.join(" "));
      if (typeof evaled !== "string") evaled = require("util").inspect(evaled);
      const avtr = message.author.avatarURL() || message.author.defaultAvatarURL;
      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(client.name, client.avatar)
        .setTitle(command.name)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setColor(client.color.default)
        .addField("**Input**",  '```' + args.join(" ") + '```')
        .addField("**Result**", '```' + Essentials.clean(evaled) + '```')
        .setFooter(`${message.author.username} evaled`, avtr);
      message.channel.send(embed);
    } catch (err) {
      const embed = Essentials.errorEmbed(err);
      message.channel.send((embed), { split: true });
    }
  }
};
````

---

I've tried a lot of combinations, ranging from actually putting it outside of the Event Handler and straight to the `bot.js` until actually using `eval()`, shown above is my current code. NO error codes were thrown, and all of the other components in `ready.js` works, including `client.footer = ...`, except for setting the activity, did I miss something?

Comment: Please show relevant code, and paste the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: No error message, and it just doesn't set the activity, all those codes are relevant since `bot.js` routes to `ready.js` which calls `essentials.js` to use it's functions. `eval.js` was just to show how the eval command is and how it worked. @ChrisG